# Why I can't execute this Pytho subprocess command on my Windows 10 machine?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am not yet so into Python and I have the following problem (I am studying a course of Python applied to security).

On my Windows 10 machine there is installed **Python 2.7.17** version.

Then I have this very simple script:

```
#!/usr/env/bin python

import subprocess

command = "msg you have been hacked !!!"

# Popen() continue the program and doesn't wait that the command is completly finished to terminate the script execution:
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

The problem is that when I try to execute it I am obtaining this error:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\python_evil>python execute_command.py

C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\python_evil>you inesistente o disconnesso
```

The error seems very strange to me (and it is half in english (you) and half in italian). Basically it says: **you doesn'te exist or disconntected**

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue and correctly execute this command?

Comment: This is not really a question about Python, but a question about the `msg` program.

Answer (score 0):

> The error seems very strange to me (and it is half in english (you) and half in italian). Basically it says: you doesn'te exist or disconntected

The `you` comes from the command, which is why it appears in English. The rest comes from Windows, which is why it appears in Italian (your localized language).

If you try `msg` by itself in a command window, you get the usage info, which explains the problem:

```
Send a message to a user.
MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}
    [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]

  username            Identifies the specified username.
  sessionname         The name of the session.
  sessionid           The ID of the session.
  @filename           Identifies a file containing a list of usernames,
                      sessionnames, and sessionids to send the message to.
  *                   Send message to all sessions on specified server.
  /SERVER:servername  server to contact (default is current).
  /TIME:seconds       Time delay to wait for receiver to acknowledge msg.
  /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
  /W                  Wait for response from user, useful with /V.
  message             Message to send.  If none specified, prompts for it
                      or reads from stdin.
```

What happens is that `msg you have been hacked !!!` is interpreted by the shell as a `msg` command, where `you` is the (username or session name or session ID), and `have been hacked !!!` is the message. But there is no user on your system named `you`, and there is no login session with that name or ID, so the `msg` program produces an error - it can't determine who is supposed to see the message.

By the way: especially as someone studying security, you really, really should update your Python installation. The 2.x branch is [no longer maintained, even for security reasons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/) and the final ever release (of code frozen since jan 1) is in the pipeline. The [most recent version on the website is 3.8.2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-382/).